# how to get only one subdocument using $in

Tags: python, mongodb, search, pymongo

how do i get the right sub document? because here i got "all"!

```
db.users.find({"produit_up.tags":{"$in":["ddsfdsf"]}}).distinct("produit_up")
Out[1]: 
[{u'abus': 0,
 u'avctype': u'image/jpeg',
 u'date': u'2012-09-15',
 u'description': u'ddsfdsf sdfsdfsdf',
 u'id': u'alucaard134773657029',
 u'namep': u'nokia 3310',
 u'nombre': 2,
 u'orientation': u'portrait',
 u'photo': ObjectId('5054d3fa3a5f3a0598b792a2'),
 u'prix': 24,
 u'tags': [u'ddsfdsf', u'sdfsdfsdf'],
 u'vendu': False},
{u'abus': 0,
 u'avctype': u'image/jpeg',
 u'date': u'2012-09-15',
 u'description': u'dfsdfdsf dsfsdfdsfsdf dsfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf',
 u'id': u'alucaard134773653643',
 u'namep': u'iphone 4gs',
 u'nombre': 2,
 u'orientation': u'portrait',
 u'photo': ObjectId('5054d3d83a5f3a0598b792a0'),
 u'prix': 18,
 u'tags': [u'dfsdfdsf', u'dsfsdfdsfsdf', u'dsfsdfsdf', u'sdfsdfsdf'],
 u'vendu': False}]
```

am sorry for the tags, i was just trying to add new elements, and i got this :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is only one matching subdocument for each document (or you are happy to only return the first matching subdocument) you can use the [positional operator ($)](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator).

Example of using this in the `mongo` shell:

> db.users.find({"produit_up.tags":{$in:["ddsfdsf"]}},{"produit_up.$":1})

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5055a7abac2ec70755816f7b"),
    "produit_up" : [
        {
            "abus" : 0,
            "avctype" : "image/jpeg",
            "date" : "2012-09-15",
            "description" : "ddsfdsf sdfsdfsdf",
            "id" : "alucaard134773657029",
            "namep" : "nokia 3310",
            "nombre" : 2,
            "orientation" : "portrait",
            "photo" : ObjectId("5054d3fa3a5f3a0598b792a2"),
            "prix" : 24,
            "tags" : [
                "ddsfdsf",
                "sdfsdfsdf"
            ],
            "vend" : false
        }
    ]
}
```

If you want to return multiple matching subdocuments for each document, you could use the new [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) in MongoDB 2.2:

```
db.users.aggregate(

    // Match on indexed `tags` field to limit results
    { $match : { "produit_up.tags":"ddsfdsf" }},

    // Convert produit_up array embedded docs to a stream of documents  
    { $unwind: "$produit_up" },

    // Find all matching subdocuments
    { $match : { "produit_up.tags":"ddsfdsf" }}
)
```

Comment: thank you ;D
that worked! and here is the equivalent in python (you just add the  -dont display in the comment, it's the &quot; sign- where there is not)

db.users.find({"produit_up.tags":{"$in":["ddsfdsf"]}}, {"produit_up.$":1})

Comment: by the way, the "1" here means how many subdocuments is matching? so 100 means it gives 100 sub documents?

Comment: The `{"produit_up.$":1}` is referring to inclusion of that subdocument in the results.  With the projection operator it will only ever match the first subdocument for each document.  If you want multiple matching subdocuments you would need to use an aggregation approach such as the Aggregation Framework or Map/Reduce.

Comment: dont know if it's a bug, but it seems that it accepts any integer, tried this and it worked:

list(db.users.find({"produit_up.tags":{"$in":["ddsfdsf"]}}, {"produit_up.$":27}))

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp: Technically the field inclusion is checking for a True or False value.  You can use a different integer or string that evaluates to true, but it won't change the number of results returned.  In Python it would be clearer to use the `True` constant, instead of `1`.

Comment: got in :D
in python, you can also use 1, try this: 1 or 0....
Out[2]: 1.....

0 or 0....
Out[3]: 0

... thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

Use limit.

```
db.users.find({"produit_up.tags":{"$in":["ddsfdsf"]}}).limit(1);
```

Comment: it dident work, the limit is only for document (to free the memory) and not for subdocuments

Comment: yes, find_one (python version) also returns the root document and not the sub document